# extract value from text file using shell script

Tags: shell, curl

I have used curl to get the response from the restapi and below is the response which came and which i am saving in the text file in location for example c:/rest_api/response.txt.

```
{"@odata.context":"https://hosted.com/RestApi/v1/$metadata#Edm.String","value":"_tlCijtcSZG0CNTl_cnFxmkz2rjbQtSJQ"}
```

As there will be new value everytime during response from the restapi, i want to use shell script or not sure if possible with curl just to extract only the value from this text file everytime and save it in new file but not sure how to do it:

```
_tlCijtcSZG0CNTl_cnFxmkz2rjbQtSJQ
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like valid json.  Use jq. Replace my `echo` with your `curl`:

```
$ echo '{"@odata.context":"h...","value":"_tlCijtcSZG0CNTl_cnFxmkz2rjbQtSJQ"}' \
    | jq -r .value
_tlCijtcSZG0CNTl_cnFxmkz2rjbQtSJQ
```

In other words, just do `curl ... | jq -r .value > /output/path`

Comment: i dont understand where to provide response.txt location in curl to read the file in your script ?

Comment: `curl` doesn't read from `response.txt`, `curl` writes to it.  You just need to pipe the output of `curl` to `jq`.  (Or have `jq` read from response.txt)

Comment: so in the same curl command where i am extracing the response from restapi and saving it in response.txt file everytime, i can use jq -r .value > /output/path at the end so that it extract only the value string in the new output file ?

Comment: Yes: `curl ... | jq ... > /output/file` will put just the value in `/output/file`.

Comment: i tried at the end in the same curl command | jq -r .value > c:/rest_api/response.txt\test.txt and getting error as ['jq' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: It would seem you do not have `jq` installed.  You would need to install it in order to use it.

Comment: As i am using this curl command in ODI tool where i cannot install jq...is there any other alternative may be with shell script ?